# Fundamental theorem of algebra: a proof for undergrads?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, alternative-proof

The fundamental theorem of algebra is the statement that a complex polynomial of positive degree has at least one root. I do not know complex analysis but I searched for proofs of the statement and came across proofs using complex analysis which seemed rather short and elegant. This is to say: I am aware that there exist very easy proofs using tools of complex analysis. Since I do not know complex analysis yet I started to wonder if there are any known proofs that are short and easy that use only tools that a first year undergrad knows? Like real analysis and linear algebra?

Comment: Spivak's book Calculus has an accessible proof.

Comment: For a first yearer it is going to be a little hard and not precisely because of the mathematical level itself but because of the abstraction level required. There's a paper (in italian) with 14 differnet proofs of the FTA, but all of them, AFAIK, are of higher level than first underg. year. Even the shortest proof I know, that of Loya's, requires some complex analysis...

Comment: @DonAntonio What is the shortest proof? If you are allowed the assume things, the shortest proof has to be that every polynomial map lifts to an endomorphism of the Riemann sphere which, being a compact Riemann surface, is either constant or surjective.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, read this paper of 1.2 pages: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/papers/LoyaFTA.pdf It doesn't require topology nor complex analysis, though **some** complex numbers stuff is included (but, for example, it is at high school level of complex numbers). By "shortest" I also meant, of course, very elementary.

Comment: If you've taken Abs Alg (Galois Theory) let me know and I can send you one that only requires the intermediate value theorem. All of them require some degree of analysis--no escaping that. I guess Abs Alg isn't really a freshman course but then again neither is real analysis which you say you are familiar with.

Comment: The usual proofs are not very hard. You may have a look at [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/06/fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-two-proofs.html) where two proofs are presented and the second one uses a bare minimum of algebra and analysis and is sort of a gem.

Comment: @DonAntonio your link is down.

Comment: [Isaiah Lankham, Bruno Nachtergaele, Anne Schilling, *Linear Algebra As an Introduction to Abstract Mathematics*, 2016](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/linear_algebra/mat67_course_notes.pdf) also has an elementary proof of the FTA (see Theorem 3.2.2). Though at a first look, it seems to be the same as the first proof in the blog post referenced by @ParamanandSingh.

Comment: As for the dead link posted by @DonAntonio, I suspect based on its file name that it is [Paul Loya, *An(other) elementary proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tadeusz_Ostrowski2/post/how_many_proofs_available_for_fundamental_theorem_of_algebra/attachment/59d626e679197b80779852e6/AS%3A323631450656771%401454171158425/download/LoyaFTA.pdf). Should this one, too, go down, search for it on http://web.archive.org .

Answer (score 9):

Here are three accessible proofs, via Keith Conrad:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/fundthmalg/fundthmalgcalculus.pdf

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/fundthmalg/fundthmalglinear.pdf

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/fundthmalg/propermaps.pdf

(the last one requires a bit more sophistication, but isn't too bad)

Comment: Perhaps the second proof is the closest to a regular first years undergraduate level, and even that is doubtable. The other two use stuff which is usually covered after first year.

Comment: @DonAntonio I disagree. The OP said "like linear algebra and analysis". Anyone with that background should be able to understand the first two with a bit of elbow grease. Admittedly, the last proof does seem a little to hard in these circumstances.

Comment: linear algebra is a wide subject and in my experience inner product, eigenvalues and stuff many times isn't covered in first year, and even if it is Hermitian and complex linear algebra, as required in Conrad's paper (not much, but still) already seems above the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 5):

There is a proof using linear algebra due to Derksen :

H.Derksen, The fundamental Theorem of Algebra and Linear Algebra, Amer. Math. Monthly, 110, (2003), 620-623. http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hderksen/preprint.html

A somewhat expanded version of it is also available (due to S. Kumaresan) :

http://main.mtts.org.in/expository-articles (See #15 under "Analysis")

Comment: Note that the second link Alex Youcis gave is a modification of Derksen's proof.

Comment: I think your first link is down.

Answer (score 1):

> > Following proof is an *ad hoc* proof designed for FTA so that every undergraduate can follow it without studying general path integrals in the Real or Complex plane.

If we suppose that our polynomial $P(z)$ **doesn't vanish** in the Complex plane, then $1/P(z)$ is a continuous function. Since the components of the polynomial $P(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions, we can infer that the components of $1/P(x,y)=u/(u^2(x,y) + v^2(x,y))+i(-v(x,y))/(u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y))$ also satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. Therefore, by the simple special case of Green's theorem in a disk, we have the Cauchy Integral Theorem in a disk for the function $1/P(z)$ and in turn the Gauss Meanvalue Theorem for the function $1/P(z)$.

We know that $1/P(0)$ is not zero, but due to the Gauss Meanvalue Theorem  $1/P(0) \rightarrow 0$ as the radius of the disk goes to infinity - a desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof (probably the most well known one) mentioned in Lang's Analysis book.

Let $ f(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0 $ be a complex polynomial of degree $ n > 0 $. (We can write $ f(0) $ instead of $ a_0 $)

We'll show $ f $ must have a root.

- $ |f(z)| \to \infty $ as $ |z| \to \infty $

> $ |f(z)| = |z|^n \left| a_n + \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \dfrac{a_0}{z^n}\right| $, and terms $ |z|^n \to \infty $ and $ \left| a_n + \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \dfrac{a_0}{z^n} \right| \to |a_n| (\neq 0) $ as $ |z| \to \infty $.

- So there is an $ R > 0 $ such that $ |f(z)| > |f(0)| $ whenever $ |z| > R $. Also $ z \mapsto |f(z)| $, defined on the compact disk $ \{ z : |z| \leq R \} $, attains its minimum at some point $ z_0 $ in the disk.
- Now $ | f(z_0) | \leq | f(z) | $ for all $ z \in \mathbb{C} $ (that is, $ \min_{z \in \mathbb{C}} |f(z)| $ exists and is $ | f(z_0) | $)

> For points with $ |z| \leq R $ we anyways have $ |f(z_0)| \leq |f(z)| $.
> For points with $ |z| > R $, we have $ |f(z_0)| \leq |f(0)| < |f(z)| $

We'll now show $ f(z_0) = 0 $.

---

Say to the contrary $ f(z_0) \neq 0 $.

Writing $ f(z) $ as a polynomial in $ (z-z_0) $ [by replacing each $ z^j $ with $ ((z-z_0)+z_0)^j $ and expanding], $$ f(z) = f(z_0) + b_1 (z-z_0) + \ldots + b_n (z-z_0)^n $$

As $ b_n \neq 0 $, there is a least $ j $ such that $ b_j \neq 0 $. Call it $ p $.

So $$ f(z) = f(z_0) + b_p (z-z_0)^p + (z-z_0)^{p+1} g(z-z_0) \, ; \, b_p \neq 0 $$ where $ g(z-z_0) $ is a polynomial in $ (z-z_0) $.

Putting $ z = z_0 + t \delta $ where $ \delta \in \mathbb{C} $ and $ t \in (0,1) $, and dividing by $ f(z_0) $,

$$ \dfrac{f(z_0 + t \delta)}{f(z_0)}  = 1 + c_p \delta^p t^p +\delta^{p+1} t^{p+1} G(t\delta) \, ; \, c_p \neq 0 $$

Fixing $ \delta $ such that $ c_p \delta^p = (-1) $, $$ \dfrac{f(z_0 + t \delta)}{f(z_0)} = 1 - t^p + t^{p+1} \varphi(t) $$ [where $ \varphi(t) = \delta^{p+1} G(t \delta) $ is a complex polynomial in variable $ t \in (0,1) $]

Notice $ \varphi(t)
 $ is bounded [$|\varphi(t)|$ is always $ \leq $ sum of absolute values of coefficients of $ \varphi $], say by $ K > 0 $.

Now taking absolute value,

$$\begin{align} \left| \dfrac{f(z_0 + t \delta)}{f(z_0)} \right| &\leq 1 - t^p + t^{p+1} |\varphi(t)| \\ &< 1 - t^p + t^{p+1} K \\ &= 1 - t^p (1 - tK) \end{align} $$ and RHS is $ < 1 $ for all $ t \in (0,1) $ with $ 1-tK > 0 $.

So we could find a point $ z_0 + t \delta $ at which $ |f(z_0 + t \delta) | < |f(z_0)| $, contradicting that $ |f(z_0)| = \min_{z \in \mathbb{C}} |f(z)| $.

Therefore $ f(z_0) $ must indeed be $ 0 $, as needed.